# What if cout is used inside overloaded output operator function?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, cout

I have the following code with the overload output operator in it:

```
class Student 
{
public:
    string name;
    int age;
    Student():name("abc"), age(20){}
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Student&);
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Student& s)
{
    os << s.name; // Line 1
    return os;
}
```

I was wondering what the difference if I changed `Line 1` into this: `cout << s.name`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then the `operator <<` would advertise that it can output the student's name to any stream, but ignore its parameter and always output to standard out. As an analogy, it would be similar to writing

```
int multiplyByTwo(int number) {
    return 4;
}
```

You can see that this is definitely a problem. If you really wanted to always return 4, then the function should have been

```
int multiplyTwoByTwo() {
    return 4;
}
```

Of course you cannot make `operator <<` take only one argument because it's a binary operator so that's where the analogy breaks down, but you get the picture.

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't call `operator <<` on `os`, but on `cout`. `cout` is also an `ostream`, but not the only one.

For example, if you wanted to output to a file, you'd have an `fstream`. And you write

```
fstream fs;
Student s;
fs << s;
```

the output wouldn't be printed to the file, but to `cout`, which isn't what you want.

It's like saying, "you can output a Student to any `ostream` you want, it's still gonna be printed to the console".

Comment: Technically you can redirect stdout to go to the file :)